# Access WifiManager by using Java called in Unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I'm trying to scan all available wifi AP nad get signal strenght. My app is made in Unity and call Java scripts by AndroidJavaClass. Problem is on Java side. I have never even seen Java and have problems with permissions.

When I called `"context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)"`

I got error, that I dont have permissions even thou I have

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

at AndroitManifest.xml.

In tutorials and forums they said, that

> you need to ask for premissions at runtime, when you are asking for
>   "Dangerous permission".

But ACCESS_WIFI_STATE is listed in Normal premissions (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html). Do I still need to ask for permission at runtime?

Because when I tried:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
```

code I found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html
I've got error:

```
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at com.addcomponenet.unitynativeplugin.WifiInspector.getWifiName(WifiInspector.java:28)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.none.database_pokus3_1-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.none.database_pokus3_1-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.none.database_pokus3_1-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
02-13 09:32:27.710: E/Unity(32477):     at dalvik.system.Bas
```

and here I am lost. Any solution? What I found did not make any sense to me.

Comment: I dont think it is related to the permission at the moment. I think you should 1. clean the project and than try building.
2. if it doesnt work, than check for the support library.

Comment: So, I have tried clear and build project and dnothing changed. I looked for support libraries, try add them to the project, but add: "compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2'" or "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'" to "dependencies" and include to project did not help.

Comment: you have to keep the version of both the lib same. 26.0.2 will never work with 26.0.0 .. Either both should have 26.0.2 or 26.0.0